# Google Analytics - is ga.js cached?

Tags: javascript, caching, google-analytics

This is the code google recommends you use to call in the ga.js file:

```
(function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();
```

as the file is inserted into the dom does this prevent the js file from being cached by the browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Caching is based on response headers for the ga.js file. It is dynamically inserted so that its loaded asynchronously, meaning the load doesn't block the browser from doing other activities (rendering, painting etc). A few browsers understand the async attribute in the script tag. Note the

```
ga.async = true;
```

Comment: Just clarifying: No, the code does not prevent the js file from being cached, and yes, ga.js is cached.

Comment: This isn't accurate. the `ga.async = true` is only recognized by a very small set of browsers. It's the style of insertion that makes it asynchronous for most browsers, not the `async` attribute being set.

Comment: Thanks to all. Good answer and clarifications are very helpful too.

Comment: Aravindan is correct that caching will not be prevented. But yc is also correct that only a small number of browsers currently support the HTML5 async attribute. That's why GA uses script insertion, which makes loading asynchronous in all the other browsers (except Opera).